# sbt gen-idea fails : trying to import a sbt-managed project TopNotch from github

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have done git clone on the TopNotch project from github and wanted to import this sbt project to Intellij.

I am under the root directory of TopNotch and have sbt gen-idea, it failed with "Not a valid command"
Link to TopNotch: https://github.com/blackrock/TopNotch

So, I have added the below lines under project/plugins.sbt but still fails with

"bt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.7.0-SNAPSHOT: not found"

Lines added:(also tried with 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT"

resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
addSbtPlugin(dependency="com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.7.0-SNAPSHOT")

I have SBT-0.13.11 installed but the build has 0.13.8
Scala - 2.11.8
Java 1.8
Intellij - 2016.1.3

Please suggest how to import the project.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*sbt-idea* plugin had been unsupported since it was included into official Scala plugin about two years ago, and project files generated by outdated version of the plugin are not compatible with IntelliJ IDEA starting with version 14, if I recall correctly.

The common approach is to install Scala plugin from IDEA (Settings > Plugins > Install JetBrains Plugin > search for Scala) and import your SBT project using the standard *Open...* dialog afterwards.

Comment: Hi Sergey, Thank you. I have added the scala plugin and have imported the project. I have compiled using sbt console from the Intellij terminal. This project does not have .Idea_module folder(which gets created by sbt-idea) but has .idea. Is this an error?

Comment: And in the module(under Project Structure) I can see 2 items: topnotch and topnotch-build. Under topnotch I don't see the scala compiler. Is this required?

Comment: Hi Sergey, I am able to successfully run a new project - Hello world created as Scala project with scala sdk. But the problem occurs when I try to create as sbt project. This TopNotch imports as sbt project.

Comment: Hi Sergey, I am able to run a sample Hello work as sbt project.

Comment: @RevathyMurugesan, `.idea` over `.idea_module` is fine - this is exactly the reason old sbt-plugin is incompatible with current version of the IDE

Comment: `topnotch-build` is the meta-project in IDEA containing the information about how to build your project. It's empty when your project contains only the `build.sbt` file, but make sure not to skip it